# POST Request to couchdb from PHP

Tags: php, database, rest, nosql, couchdb

Trying to add a document to couchdb from php program .
i wanted to use couchdb auto generated uuid as key.
the below code is giving an  error as

```
CONTENT TYPE MUST BE APPLICATION/JSON
```

```
  $couch = new CouchSimple();
  $resp=$couch->send("POST",'/aaa-stores','{"foo":"bar"}');
  $json=json_decode($resp);
  if(isset($json->{'error'}))
        {
         echo $json->{'reason'};
        }



class CouchSimple {

   private $host = "localhost" ,$port = 5984,$user=" ",$pass =" ";

function send($method, $url, $post_data = NULL)
{
    $s = fsockopen($this->host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr);
    if(!$s) {
        echo "$errno: $errstr\n";
         return false;
    }
   $request = "$method $url HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $this->host\r\n";
   if ($this->user) 
      {        
        $request .= "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$this->user :$this->pass")."\r\n";
      }
 if($post_data) {
    $request .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_data)."\r\n\r\n";
    $request .= 'Content-Type: application/json'."\r\n\r\n";
    $request .= "$post_data\r\n";
    }
else {
    $request .= "\r\n";
     }
fwrite($s, $request);
$response = "";
while(!feof($s)) {
    $response .= fgets($s);
}
 list($this->headers, $this->body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response);
 return $this->body;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the content of $request before you call fwrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here.  You could try using a library for CouchDB (such as https://github.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/php-couchdb - disclaimer, I'm the maintainer of that project).

As a minimum it would be good to use a more fully-featured HTTP library for PHP, such as Guzzle (http://guzzlephp.org/).  This will make it easier to add headers and encode the body without needing to output raw HTTP from your PHP code.  Here's a blog post showing how to use Guzzle to talk to CouchDB from PHP that might also be helpful: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/07/27/get-started-with-couchdb-php-guzzle/

Final tip: try using http://requestb.in to get a URL to use to test what request you are sending - it really helps with debugging this sort of thing in my experience.